# How to use application.properties in org.quartz.Job Class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I have created a spring boot application to implement Quartz scheduler. In Job class, I want to use some property from application.properties. How to inject that?

I have tried below but getting null:

```
    @Component
public class ScheduleJob implements org.quartz.Job {

        private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(ScheduleJob.class);

        public ScheduleJob() {
        }

        @Value("${ijobs.service.url}")
        private String ijobsUrl;

        public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {

            LOGGER.info("Job exceution starts--->");
              System.out.println("-------------------"+ijobsUrl);
```

Comment: Spring Boot has built-in support for Quartz. It automatically creates a Quartz Scheduler bean with the configuration that we supplied in the application.properties file. That’s why we could directly inject the Scheduler in the controller.

Comment: Which property are you specifically looking for ?

Comment: I have injected Quartz scheduler. But in job class i want to call a url which I want to pick from property file.

Answer (score 1):

Spring requires annotating the class with @Component for it to manage it (including loading any properties into the class).  If you use "new" to create the object, then it is outside Spring's control and it won't inject the dependencies/values into it.

On side note, there is native support for Quartz if using Spring Boot: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-quartz.html

Comment: using component but still getting value as null

Comment: How are you creating the ScheduleJob?    You need to have the following to use it:    

@Component
public class QuartzSetup {
    
      @ Autowired ScheduleJob job;

      // code to make use of job
}

Comment: The fact that Spring is not failing to create the component due to the property missing, suggests Spring is not creating the object.

Comment: Yes, by default your Job subclass instance is not created by Spring.
You can either:
a) setup Job Factory as a Spring bean which would autowire the dependencies during creation
b) or call this as a first line in your Job's execute() method:
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `ScheduleJob` class should be annotated with `@Component` for spring to manage it. Secondly, if you want any property to be injected you could do it in a similar way to how you are injecting value of `ijobsUrl`.

put your required property in application.properties

```
@Value("${my.property}")
private String myProperty
```

Comment: Tried the same but still getting null.

Comment: from where are you fetching the property ijobs.service.url ?

Comment: from application.properties